# Ng-click does not work outside of my tr tag AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an app and I cant seem to figure out why my ng-click only works inside of my (single) tr tag but as soon as I put it into another tr tag it stop working. Keep in mind it was working before I used the ng-repeat within the first tr tag. Here is what my code looks like, any advice would greatly help!

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td ng-click="commentOpen = !commentOpen">
                <div class="iconsize">Comment Closed</div>
            </td>
            <td ng-click="switchOpen = !switchOpen">
                <div class="iconsize">Switch Closed</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div ng-show="commentOpen == true">
                    <textarea>Comment Open</textarea>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="switchOpen == true">
                    <p>Switch On</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the ng-repeat on the  tag which was causing my ng-click to not fire. I ended up moving my ng-repeat to the tbody and the ng-click and ng-show started working again.

Answer (score 0):

`ngRepeat` creates new scopes for its children, it just usually seems like it's accessing the same scope because this new scope inherits from its parent.

Meaning, `commentOpen` is actually referring to a property on the wrong scope.

Below are three potential ways for you to fix this:

1) `controller as`, and always refer to the controller you're after by name

2) `$parent.commentOpen` (Don't do this! It becomes very confusing as you nest)

3) Instead of `commentOpen` and `switchOpen`, you can use an Object (e.g. `$scope.openControls = { comment: false, switch: false }`, and then in the td tags you would write something like  `ng-click='openControls.comment = !openControls.comment'`). This way it's passed inherited by reference (where as a boolean would be by value), and keeps synced.