# how to properly show and hide elements in my case

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a weird question regarding the no-show

I have something like

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" >
        <a ng-click="showNew =! showNew">{{item.text}}
            <span ng-show="showNew">New Items!</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-show="showNew">
        <a >Category 1 </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For some reason, only the '`New Items!`' was shown when I click `a` tag. The Category 1 would never show. I thought showNew would be in the same scope for everything in my case. How do I solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're changing a boolean property on the new scope that `ngRepeat` created. There are several ways to fix this ( I outline 3 potential solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30483694/624590 ). The best solution would probably be to have an object (e.g.  `scope.itemsParams = { isVisible: false }` ) or something along those lines and to use, for example `ng-show="itemsParams.showNew"` . That way they're both referring to the same `itemsParams` Object by reference, can both observe the same `isVisible` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init to create the variable higher up in the template and that should help. This is not an ideal fix but it is quick and easy if you don't want to edit other files.

EDIT: you will need to use dot notation in your model so the angular scope magic can work. (this is the equivolent of $scope.nested = {showNew: false}

```
<ul ng-app ng-init="nested.showNew=false">
    <li ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3]" >
        <a ng-click="nested.showNew =! nested.showNew">{{$index}}
            <span ng-show="nested.showNew">New Items!</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-show="nested.showNew">
        <a >Category 1 </a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0692dbak/

Comment: That won't work. Proof here: http://jsfiddle.net/vj85z0vk/ , using the same `ngInit` format. The problem is that `ngRepeat` creates a new `scope` object for each item, and copies over the properties of the parent's scope. If these are primitives (numbers, strings, booleans), the parent's value won't also be updated when the item changes.

Comment: If you're referring to a more complex Object, copying by value is okay because it's just a reference to the Object (rather than it being the actual value, as in a primitive). Changing its properties will reflect on both sides. Here's the same example switched to Objects: http://jsfiddle.net/vj85z0vk/1/

Comment: Sorry, forgot the obvious gotcha. If you use dot notation it will work (but as I say this is a fix not a resolution, the rest of the OP code is needed to do that properly and less hacky) @DRobinson

Comment: Yep. That will work. If there's a `$scope.nested` defined in the controller then you'll run into problems. Accessing via `$parent` (such as: `ng-click="$parent.showNew =! $parent.showNew"`) feels safer, and requires less boilerplate, even though I can't recommend that solution either. As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/0om8b8nd/1/